# String issue for shopify customer object {{customer.id}}

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

```
$customer_id = "{{customer.id}}";
```

I get customer id from shopify using above statement. and when I print it using echo it show me 123456789012.
But when I var_dump it show me string(15) "123456789012".

and when I used it in if condition it's give me different result for e.g

```
if($customer_id == '123456789012'){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Out put:
false

but I want true.

Comment: You have some unprintable characters in the `id`. `var_dump('123456789012');` gives `string(12) "123456789012"`

Comment: @Nick but when I used str_split it return me an array with each character of string i.e {,{,c,u,s,t,o,m,e,r,.,i,d,},}  that's why I got length 15 so have you any suggestion to solved this

Comment: If that is what `str_split` gives you then how can `var_dump` give you `string(15) "123456789012"`? It should give you `string(15) "{{customer.id}}"`

Comment: Assuming you are inside your own PHP App here (you have to be to be using PHP after all), why are you trying to parse Liquid? Makes no sense. It seems like you are confusing running your PHP and Shopify in the same context.

Comment: @David Thanks for replying but I have to need display customer data in one page and in my url there is a id of deal but some othere customer directly change id in url (pass id which is not belong him) he is able to show data  I want to prevent these so i need to check id is belong to login customer or not so i need custome id hope you understand my issue...

Comment: You can use an App Proxy. Obviously you cannot use PHP in Shopify. A simple Ajax callback to the App with the customer ID can verify a logged in customer or not.